# C# .NET Window won't show in front after double clicking on listview row

Tags: c#, .net, listview, window

I have this one problem that I can't get over. I think it will be something really simple but I just was not able to find out.. I am trying to open new window here for editing contact when user double click on one row in listview. Window normally opens but the problem is it won't open in front of current main window but behind it so it is not visible and can easily confuse user. I have tried few methods like BringIntoView() or playing with focus but nothing helped.

Please help me with this. Thanks!

Code:

```
void ListViewItem_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    editContact();
}


private void editContact()
{
    Window1 win = new Window1("edit");
    DatabaseHandler handler = new DatabaseHandler();
    win.Show();
    List<Contact> listie = handler.GetContactList();
    var selected = listview_contacts.SelectedItem as Contact;
    win.textbox_id.Text = selected.cId.ToString();
    win.textbox_name.Text = selected.Name.ToString();
    win.textbox_address.Text = selected.Address.ToString();
    win.textbox_email.Text = selected.Email.ToString();
    win.textbox_name.Focus();
    win.textbox_name.SelectionStart = win.textbox_name.Text.Length;
}
```

Comment: Hard to know where to start with this. Is this meant to be a non modal window. (a modal window is like a dialog, you have to fill it in and hit "ok" before you can go back to it's parent). Or is it more like a tool bar, where you can flip between windows?

Comment: Hmm just spotted you are creating it, so I'm going to assume modal, unless you wanted a huge memory leak..

Comment: It is meant to be modal window in this case. It is custom small window that shows up in center of the screen with data from listview in textboxes which user can change and there are two buttons "Save" and "Close" that saves the changes back to database and refresh and sort the listview. I am also using this Window1 for adding new contacts when I input "new" instead of "edit" as a parameter. It has the same looks only different type of usage and header. For new contact I call it with button and it shows up normally in front of main window.

Comment: ShowDialog is what you want then. There are lot better ways to implement this though. For instance what it you wanted in the Window1 for to give textbox1 a more meaningful name, or change it to a combox box for another variant. You'd have to change every formw that used the window1 form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void editContact()
{
   using(Window1 win = new Window1("edit"))
   {
      DatabaseHandler handler = new DatabaseHandler();
      List<Contact> listie = handler.GetContactList();
      var selected = listview_contacts.SelectedItem as Contact;
      win.textbox_id.Text = selected.cId.ToString();
      win.textbox_name.Text = selected.Name.ToString();
      win.textbox_address.Text = selected.Address.ToString();
      win.textbox_email.Text = selected.Email.ToString();
      win.textbox_name.Focus();
      win.textbox_name.SelectionStart = win.textbox_name.Text.Length;
      win.ShowDialog();
      // do something with whatever win1 did.
      // if its say OK Cancrl form
      // if (win.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) { // do something }
   }
}
```

Will probably fix your issue. However without seeing the rest of your code, or knowing your intent, I can't tell you exactly how badly you've gone wrong.
For example at least all the code setting up win.textbox, should be in win...

Comment: Thanks! Problem was solved with using ShowDialog() and using it as last instruction as you were showing here.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
win.ShowDialog();
```

Which should open the new windows as a modal window.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
win.Show(this);
```

This will enable the user to interact with the main form when your editing dialog opens.
Or you can try

```
win.ShowDialog();
```

This will block the main form when your editing dialog opens.

Comment: Using win.show means win should not be created each time edit is done. You'd end up with loads of them.